# Express: Unable to route

Tags: javascript, express

On my home page i have a student login button. On clicking i want to redirect to a login page. But i am not getting request inside login route.

server.js file

```
const express=require('express');
const path=require('path');
const bodyparser=require('body-parser');
const session=require('express-session');
const{v4:uuidv4}=require('uuid');

const router=require('./router');

const app=express();

const port=process.env.PORT||3000;

app.arguments(bodyparser.json())
app.arguments(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}))

app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.arguments(session({
    secret:uuidv4(),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));


app.use('/route',router)

//home route
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('home');
})

app.listen(port,()=>{console.log("Listening to the server on http://localhost:3000")});
```

router.js file

```
var express=require('express');
var router=express.Router();


//student login page
router.get("/studentlogin",(req,res)=>{
    res.end("Login Successfull");
})

Module.exports=router;
```

views/home.ejs file

```
 <form action="/route/studentlogin">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary align-items-end" value="Student Login">
 </form>
```

What i am expecting is to print login successfull but i am getting error.

Error

> Cannot GET /route/studentlogin

Comment: it's a typo, you wrote `studnetlogin` instead of `studentlogin`

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski i corrected it even though getting same error

Comment: First, I'm getting an error : `Module is not defined` (it's `module`, not `Module`). Then, the code crashes with `TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them`. It doesn't like `app.arguments()`. Also, `body-parser` is deprecated in favor of `express.json()`

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to use `app.use` instead of `app.arguments`
2. Replace `bodyParser` with `express`
3. Add the `cors` library to enable CORS
4. Export a module using `module.exports`

Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors')
const session = require('express-session');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

const router = require('./router');

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(cors())

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(
  session({
    secret: uuidv4(),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);

app.use('/route', router);

//home route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('home');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Listening to the server on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

router.js

```
...
module.exports=router;
```